# Why do we have to annotate a class as immutable when overriding certain fields in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why do we have to annotate a class the overrides `hashCode` and the `==` operator in dart as immutable? For example:

```dart
@immutable
class RandomClass {
  final Object identifier;

  const RandomClass({
    required this.identifier,
  });

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (other is RandomClass) {
      return other.identifier == identifier;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => identifier.hashCode;
}
```

Gives me a warning when I don't annotate `RandomClass` as immutable because I override the `==` operator

I understand the [effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74073391/mark-class-as-immutable-causes-any-effects) of marking a class as immutable, but am wondering why we have to do that when a class overrides certain fields.

Comment: You don't *have* to annotate it with `@immutable` (and annotations can't be strictly enforced anyway), but doing so avoids potential pitfalls if you ever use your type in a `Set` or as a key to a `Map`.  See https://dart.dev/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-custom-equality-for-mutable-classes

Comment: Ah, that also gives the answer since it explains why you should avoid overriding the operator for mutable classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [effective dart docs](https://dart.dev/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-custom-equality-for-mutable-classes) (thanks to @jamesdlin for linking to it).

> When you define ==, you also have to define hashCode. Both of those should take into account the object’s fields. If those fields change then that implies the object’s hash code can change.
>
> Most hash-based collections don’t anticipate that—they assume an
> object’s hash code will be the same forever and may behave
> unpredictably if that isn’t true.